# Passing arguments to a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, es6-class, polymer-2.x

I am trying to create a mixin for a Polymer 2.0 components (class based syntax) with something like below. Is there a way to pass the options to the class the way I am doing it right now?

**Polymer element definition with the mixin:**

```
class PodcastListView extends PolymerApolloBehavior(Polymer.Element, myOptions) {
   //some code 
}
```

**The mixin class:**

```
export const PolymerApolloBehavior = (superclass, options) => class extends superclass {
    constructor() {
       console.log(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you function-wrapper for your PodcastListView class that will makes a new one with new behavior. It will look something like this:

```
export const PolymerApolloBehavior = (original, options) => {
  let result = Object.assign({}, original)
  const originalConstructor = result.prototype.constructor
  result.prototype.constructor = () => {
    console.log(options) // your behavior
    originalConstructor() // original constructor
  }
  // any changes of class
  return result
}
```

And now you can apply your new behavior:

```
export default PolymerApolloBehavior(PodcastListView, {behaviorOptions})
```